# Unable to find a logic to build a json in python 2.7 from a txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

My txt file contains airlines with source and origin. If for example united airline was associated with every source and origin then I could have build JSON myself. But here the issue is United Airline and Emirates is defined once and then it has multiple source and origin.

```
United Airline

Source : UK
Origin : IN

Source : DN
Origin : VN

Emirates

Source : DU
Origin : KO

Source : KL
Origin : NP

Source : ZO
Origin : PL
```

I want to build a JSON as shown below

```
{
    "Supplier":"United Airlines",
    "Source" : "UK",
    "Origin" : "IN",
},
{
    "Supplier":"United Airlines",
    "Source" : "DN",
    "Origin" : "VN",
},
{
    "Supplier":"Emirates",
    "Source" : "DU",
    "Origin" : "KO",
},
{
    "Supplier":"Emirates",
    "Source" : "KL",
    "Origin" : "NP",
},
{
    "Supplier":"Emirates",
    "Source" : "ZO",
    "Origin" : "PL",
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("airline.txt","r") as fin:
   supplier = origin = source = ""  # init empty
   final_result = []
   for line in fin:
      line = line.strip()
      if not line:
         continue
      if ":" not in line:  # it is the supplier
          supplier = line
      elif "Source" in line:
          source = line.split(": ")[-1]
      elif "Origin" in line:
          origin = line.split(": ")[-1]
      else:
          print("Not recognized line {}".format(line))
      if all([supplier, origin, source]):
          final_result.append(OrderedDict({"Supplier":supplier,"Source":source, "Origin":origin}))
          source = origin = ""
   with open("json_output.json","a+") as fout:
      json.dump(final_result,fout)
```

Output:

```
 {"Supplier": "United Airline",
 "Source": "UK",
 "Origin": "IN"},
 {"Supplier": "United Airline",
 "Source": "DN",
 "Origin": "VN"},
 {"Supplier": "Emirates",
 "Source": "DU",
 "Origin": "KO"},
 {"Supplier": "Emirates",
 "Source": "KL",
 "Origin": "NP"},
 {"Supplier": "Emirates",
 "Source": "ZO",
 "Origin": "PL"}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy for your solution. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if not line.startswith(("Source", "Origin")):
                result.append([line])
            else:
                result[-1].append(line)

out_result = []        
for i in result:
    key = i[0]
    val = i[1:]
    for j in range(0, len(val), 2):
        data = dict(i.split(" : ") for i in val[j: j+2])
        data.update(Supplier=key)
        out_result.append(data)
print(out_result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Origin': 'IN', 'Source': 'UK', 'Supplier': 'United Airline'},
 {'Origin': 'VN', 'Source': 'DN', 'Supplier': 'United Airline'},
 {'Origin': 'KO', 'Source': 'DU', 'Supplier': 'Emirates'},
 {'Origin': 'NP', 'Source': 'KL', 'Supplier': 'Emirates'},
 {'Origin': 'PL', 'Source': 'ZO', 'Supplier': 'Emirates'}]
```